# proof that k times a limit at negative inifinity equals negative infinity.

Tags: limits, proof-explanation

below is a proof I am stuck on- I am uncertain as to where to go past the final step (If I've even done it correctly). Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: THis is a limit as $x\to \infty$... such as $f(x)= -x^3$ and not $x\to a$... such as $g(x) = -\frac 1{|x-2|$ and $\lim_{x\to 2} = -\infty$?  Right?

Comment: it is indeed x→∞ , I can't actually read the rest of what typed though.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=-\infty$$ means for any preassingned real number $N$ there exists a $m\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x) \leq (-N)$ whenever $x>m$. Now choose $N'=\frac{N}{k}$ ,$k>0$. Then there exists  $m'\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x) \leq (-N')$ whenever $x>m'$

i.e, $g(x) \leq (-\frac{N}{k})$ whenever $x>m'$

i.e, $kg(x) \leq (-\frac{N}{k}).k$ $=(-N)$ whenever $x>m'$

Answer (score 0):

Let $k>0$. The equality
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)=-\infty$$
means that for every $M<0$ there exists some $R>0$ such that $$g(x)<\frac{M}{k}<0$$ whenever $x>R$.
Now, if we multiply the last inequality by $k$ we get
$$kg(x)<M$$
which means, the number $kg(x)$ stays under $M<0$ for any choice of $ M $ as long as $ x> R $. Which means also :
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} kg(x)=-\infty$$